# SQL: Insertar registros en una tabla a partir de una consulta en otra tabla

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo que insertar en la tabla alumnado todos los valores de la tabla ALUMNADO_NUEVO. Pero quiero que todos los alumnos que inserte tengan el cod_curso = 1. El esquema de tablas os lo dejo en la figura.
He probado lo siguiente :

```
Insert into alumnado (nombre,apellidos,sexo,fecha_nac,cod_curso) 
values (select ((nombre,apellidos,sexo,fecha_nac) from alumnado_nuevo, 1)

Insert into alumnado (nombre,apellidos,sexo,fecha_nac,cod_curso) 
values (select * from alumnado_nuevo, 1)
```

devuelve ambas el mismo error

Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-00936: falta una expresión
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sintaxis del `insert`/`select` no pasa por usar la cláusula `values`, sino es de la forma:

```
insert into TablaDestino (ListadoCampos)
select ListadoCampos
  from TablaOrigen
 where Condiciones;
```

El número de campos de ambas listas debe ser el mismo y los tipos de dato del select deben ser compatibles con el tipo de dato de la columna destino. Digo *compatible* en el sentido que, debe ser el mismo tipo de dato, o uno que tenga una conversión automática al tipo de dato de destino.

Adaptando esto a tu caso, podrías hacer algo como:

```
Insert into alumnado (nombre, apellidos, sexo, fecha_nac, cod_curso) 
select nombre, apellidos, sexo, fecha_nac, 1
  from alumnado_nuevo;
```

Notas que la sentencia `select`, además de los campos de la tabla de origen, tiene una columna con el valor constante `1`, que es el que va a quedar en la columna `cod_curso` de la tabla destino.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda